# matrix gradient

Tags: derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus

I found the gradient of an optimization problem as

$$
b*I + \rho\big(-A+diag(A)+X-2diag(X)\big) = 0
$$

But my problem is, I want to find the equation for $X$. From the above equation, because of the $diag(X)$, I am not able to find a closed form for $X$. Is there any way, we can write $diag(X)$ in terms of $X$.

$diag(X)$ is the matrix containing only the diagonal entries of $X$.

The original problem is
$$
b*tr(X) + tr\big(\delta^T(A-X+diag(X)\big) + \frac{\rho}{2}\lvert\lvert A-X+diag(X)\lvert\lvert_{fro}^2
$$

$tr$ is the trace and `$fro$` Frobenius norm.

I am trying to find the value of X that minizes/maximizes the objective

---

Comment: What does $diag(X)$ mean?

Comment: it is the matrix of diagonal entries of the original matrix. edited the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the optimization problem?

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: I think the optimization problem needs to be fixed. It looks like you're adding a matrix term ($B$) to 2 scalar terms.  What kind of product does $B * {\rm tr}(X)$ represent?  Also the $\delta^T$ term is missing from the gradient.  What does it represent?

Comment: There the B is in fact a scalar and the first equation is $B*I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve for $X$ consider the diagonal and off-diagonal terms separately.

Let $F=(1-I)$, where $1$ is the matrix of all ones. Then the operations to extract the diagonal and off-diagonal terms can be represented using the Hadamard ($\circ$) product as 
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm diag}(X) &= I\circ X \cr
 {\rm offdiag}(X) &= F\circ X \cr
}$$
The equation to be solved can be written as
$$\eqalign{
 X-2I\circ X &= (A-I\circ A) - B/\rho \cr
}$$
Before we begin, note that
$$\eqalign{
 I\circ I &= I \cr
 F\circ I &= 0 \cr
}$$
The diagonal components of the equation are
$$\eqalign{
 I\circ X - 2I\circ I\circ X  &= (I\circ A-I\circ I\circ A)-I\circ B/\rho \cr
 -I\circ X  &= (0)-I\circ B/\rho \cr
 I\circ X  &= I\circ B/\rho \cr
}$$
and the off-diagonal components are
$$\eqalign{
 F\circ X - 2F\circ I\circ X  &= (F\circ A-F\circ I\circ A)-F\circ B/\rho \cr
 F\circ X - (0)  &= (F\circ A)-F\circ B/\rho \cr
 F\circ X &= F\circ(A-B/\rho) \cr
}$$
Add the two pieces together to find X
$$\eqalign{
 F\circ X + I\circ X &= F\circ(A-B/\rho) + I\circ B/\rho \cr
 X &= F\circ(A-B/\rho) + I\circ B/\rho \cr
}$$

Comment: That is some real problem solving skill. Thanks.

Comment: You can also express the result as $X=(A\!-\!B/\rho)+{\rm diag}(2B/\rho\!-\!A)$

Comment: what will the soft-thresholded solution if the first term in the original optimization problem is $||X||_1$, i.e. $\ell_1$ norm minimization.